# How to change label's name of grafana loki query result

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I want to show in grafana table statistics of every endpoints such as avg/min/max latency and number of calls each hour using loki logs as datasource.

I made 4 range queries by 1h bins.
For counting number of calls:

```
count by (httpRequest_requestUrl) (count_over_time({app="ingress-nginx"} | json [1h] ))
```

For avg/min/max latency:

```
avg/min/max_over_time({app="ingress-nginx"} | json | label_format lat= `{{ TrimSuffix .httpRequest_latency " s" }}` | unwrap lat [1h]) by (httpRequest_requestUrl)
```

I expect to have each result of query having different labels as if I was using instant query:
Value #A, Value #B, Value #C, Value #D.
[Example after **series to rows**, **merge**, and **organize fields** transformations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YZN9.png)

The result of range query:
[Mixed up queries results under **Value column**. After **series to rows** transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WRgn.png)